# How to set background colors in run-time?

Tags: smart-device, genexus

I am using GeneXus for a Smart Devices project.

I have to create a grid that will present data from a webService.
This webService will also return the RGB code that represents the background color in which the returned record should be shown.

The only way that I know of setting the background color (on the GridTable) is via the Theme class.

Is it possible to do this in execution time?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to change the background color in runtime, you can only change the theme class.

If the set of colors that will be used is known at design time, you could create a theme class for each one of them, and apply the corresponding class in runtime.

Otherwise, the only solution I can think of is creating a user control to extend the current grid functionality.